# QGIS 3.0.1 toggling categories visible/invisible

Tags: qgis, layers, editing

If I have a layer with many style categories, all but one or two set to invisible, is there a way to toggle them all visible?

The workaround is to create a duplicate of the layer with everything visible, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you right click on one of the categories you can select "Show All Items" or "Hide All Items" to toggle the visibility

[image: Toggle categories]

Comment: Thank you. I was right clicking the layer and right clicking in the properties window but never thought to try there.
Solved.